# Banach Steinhaus Theorem: Necessity of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

I came across this proof of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem in my textbook: [image]

I was wondering where exactly the author of the proof used the completeness of $V$. Does this have to do with the initial construction of $U \subset V$?

Comment: What is Theorem 3.2.12?

Comment: So it turns out it has to do with the Baire category theorem, hence completeness!

Comment: Yes, it's one of the classic corollaries of the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of applications, the Baire category theorem can be worded as:

> If a complete metric space is written as a countable union of closed subsets, then at least one of those subsets has nonempty interior.

In the proof quoted above, we have 
$$V = \bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \bigcap_{\alpha\in A} \{v:|f_\alpha(v)|\le M\}$$
because at every point $v$ there exists $M_v$ such that $|f_\alpha(v)|\le M_v$ for all $\alpha$. The sets $E_M = \bigcap_{\alpha\in A} \{v:|f_\alpha(v)|\le M\}$ are closed. Hence, at least one of them has nonempty interior, and this is where the set $U$ comes from.